# Correct method form

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This code does not compile.

```
public class Diamond {
 public static void diamondOfAsterisks(String * ) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

          System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

          System.out.print("\n");
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: or is this a puzzle to identify the question itself :)

Comment: next time list your compile error messages and specific which line is throwing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "arguments" of your method:

```
public static void diamondOfAsterisks() {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static void diamondOfAsterisks(String * )`

That won't compile! Use a valid identifier such as `star` or `asterisk`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this won't compile...

```
public static void diamondOfAsterisks(String * ) {
```

C++ Pointers convention don't apply in java...